# Accordion submenu wont slide down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Making an accordion menu its lost its slide down/up function what am I doing wrong?
Can someone check this code

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nav-pills ul li').on('click touchstart', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var checkElement = $(this).next();

        $('.nav-pills li').removeClass('open');
        $(this).closest('li').addClass('open');

        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $(this).closest('li').removeClass('open');
            checkElement.slideUp(300);
        }
        if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('nav-pills ul ul:visible').slideUp(300);
            checkElement.slideDown(300);
        }
        if($(this).closest('li').find('ul').children().length == 0){
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }); 
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="nav-container">
<div class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
  <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Is Landscape Architecture Right For Me?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/design/index.html" target="_blank">What Is Landscape Architecture?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zbx3FDDNeQM" target="_blank">I Want to Be a Landscape Architect (Video)</a>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/ContentDetail.aspx?id=12206&PageTitle=Education&RMenuId=54">What Skills Do I Need?</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.bls.gov/ooh/architecture-and-engineering/landscape-architects.htm" target="_blank">Future Career Prospects (U.S. Labor Department)</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">What Does A Landscape Architects Do?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/ContentDetail.aspx?id=22922">Interviews with Leading Landscape Architects</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/2013awards/index.html">ASLA Professional Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/2013studentawards/index.html">ASLA Student Awards</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://astore.amazon.com/a04806-20/detail/0470338458/190-5667858-4355216" target="_blank">Buy the Book:&nbsp;<em>Becoming A Landscape Architect</em></a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Why Is Their Work So Important?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/index.html">Designing Our Future: Sustainable Landscapes</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/sustainablelandscapes/videos.html">ASLA Animations</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Where Can I Study?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/schools.aspx">Picking A School</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://store.di.net/collections/reports" target="_blank">DesignIntelligence Rankings (2013)</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">How Do I Learn More?</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/uploadedFiles/CMS/Education/Career_Discovery/2013%20ASLA%20Graduating%20Students%20Report%200%202.pdf" target="_blank">Graduating Student Surveys</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.acementor.org/" target="_blank">ACE Mentor Program</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/studentchapters.aspx">Find An ASLA Student Chapter</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.asla.org/software.aspx">Learn New Software Programs</a></li>
        <li><a href="http://www.nps.gov/ncrc/programs/rtca/whatwedo/projects_by_state.html" target="_blank">Local Parks / Conservation Programs</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Personal Stories</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#">The Path</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Obstacles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aids</a></li>
      </ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">About Columbus Circle</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="http://asla.org/awards/2006/06winners/238.html">Learn More About Columbus Circle</a></li>
        <li><a href="img/0173ColCir_062_c_before.jpg">Before Photo</a></li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
    border-radius: 0px;
    line-height: 1.5;  
}

.nav-container {
    max-width: 26%;
    width: 280px;
    top: 90px;
    left: 45px;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #000000; 
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 3;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.nav .open>a, 
.nav .open>a:hover, 
.nav .open>a:focus {
    background-color: #f26527;
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown > a {
    color: #ffffff;
}

.dropdown-menu {
    border-radius: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    position: relative;
    width: 345px;
    z-index: 4;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 1.3;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover,
.dropdown-menu > li > a:focus {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #f26527;
}

.dropdown-menu li {
    font-family: "HelveticaNeue-Light", "Helvetica Neue Light", "Helvetica", "Ariel", "sans-   serif";
    font-weight: 300;
    background: #ffffff;
    line-height: 1.5;
}
```

The menu works like and accordion but again has lost its sliding function it just drops down

Thanks

Comment: your first <ul> has no closed tag! also the divs aren't closed

Comment: CSS posted! I just posted a portion of the HTML, the menu is quite long. - Closed the HTML

Pavlo touchstart is for the ipad.

Comment: Can you show it in jsFiddle?

Comment: Doesnt work at all on fiddle like it shows locally

http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/9tJyj/

Comment: I had a bunch of crap in my html, its been cleaned up. Any solutions?

updated fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/gward90/9tJyj/1/

Comment: To be blunt, this is a horrible attempt at an accordion, please just do yourself a favor and download jquery UI, and use their [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Comment: I'm sure, can you tell me what the issue is though? I already know its wrong. Is there no jquery I can write for an accordion menu to go with bootstraps nav pills ?

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this too, and if you tried all the possible solutions here, the answer is that lists cant animate, that if youre trying to animate the list.
Best way is to wrap the lists in a div.

Comment: I have the live site up with no accordion and the lists animate. Thanks for your feedback though 

http://asla.org/yourpath/index.html

Comment: Welcome, then there must be a problem somewhere, do not give in, you can do it!!!